# Unit testing custom attribute value in OnActionExecuting event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I have following implementation in my base controller from which I am deriving most of my controllers. It accounts for setting the page title, meta description and keywords for each page if the values are not set via decorator on the controller actions.

**BaseController**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Page title
        var title = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PageTitleAttribute), false);
        if (title.Length == 1)
            ViewBag.Title = ((PageTitleAttribute)(title[0])).Parameter;
        else
            ViewBag.Title = "My website title";

        //Page keywords
        var keywords = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetaKeywordsAttribute), false);
        if (keywords.Length == 1)
            ViewBag.MetaKeywords = ((MetaKeywordsAttribute)(keywords[0])).Parameter;
        else 
            ViewBag.MetaKeywords = "targeted SEO keywords";

        //Page description
        var description = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetaDescriptionAttribute), false);
        if (description.Length == 1)
            ViewBag.MetaDescription = ((MetaDescriptionAttribute)(description[0])).Parameter;
        else 
            ViewBag.MetaDescription = "My custom description";

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

The custom attributes are fairly simple:

```
public class PageTitleAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _parameter;

    public PageTitleAttribute(string parameter)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }

    public string Parameter { get { return _parameter; } }
}

public class MetaDescriptionAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _parameter;

    public MetaDescriptionAttribute(string parameter)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }

    public string Parameter { get { return _parameter; } }
}

public class MetaKeywordsAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _parameter;

    public MetaKeywordsAttribute(string parameter)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }

    public string Parameter { get { return _parameter; } }
}
```

And this is how make use of the attributes on appropirate action methods in controller:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    [PageTitle("My new website")]
    [MetaKeywords("Explicitly set keywords")]
    [MetaDescription("description goes here")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Error()
    {            
        return View();
    }
}
```

This all seems to work just fine. Now I would like to create unit test to validate that if the values are not set via attribute on action methods, the default values will be rendered as set from base controller. How can I do that? I have some tests written but I don't think they are targeting the filterContext on the basecontroller. Specifically I am looking for test for Error action method which does not have anything attribute value set. Just for reference this is what I have setup now:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Attribute_when_set_should_return_attribute_values() 
    {
        var method = typeof(HomeController).GetMethod("Index");
        var pageTitle = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PageTitleAttribute), false)
                     .Cast<PageTitleAttribute>()
                     .SingleOrDefault();
        var keywords = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetaKeywordsAttribute), false)
                     .Cast<MetaKeywordsAttribute>()
                     .SingleOrDefault();
        var description = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetaDescriptionAttribute), false)
                     .Cast<MetaDescriptionAttribute>()
                     .SingleOrDefault();

        Assert.IsNotNull(pageTitle);
        Assert.IsNotNull(keywords);
        Assert.IsNotNull(description);

        Assert.AreEqual("My new website", pageTitle.Parameter);
        Assert.AreEqual("Explicitly set keywords", keywords.Parameter);
        Assert.AreEqual("description goes here", description.Parameter);
    }
```